# MongoDB Primary replica set member syncing to secondary

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have a replica set having three members, with `host0:27100` as a primary member. Recently i changed the configuration and made the `host2:27102` as primary member. Followed [these](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/) docs.

After changing the configuratio, the `rs.status()` output says that the `host1:27101` is `"syncingTo" : "host2:27102"` which is intended.

But the output for new primary `host2:27102` shows it is `"syncingTo" : "host0:27100"` which is the previous primary member, and changed into secondary.

I cannot understand why its syncing to the secondary member. Is it a normal behavior?

```
s0:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "s0",
        "date" : ISODate("2013-09-25T12:31:42Z"),
        "myState" : 2,
        "syncingTo" : "host2:27102",
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "host0:27100",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 428068,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1380112272, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-09-25T12:31:12Z"),
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "host1:27101",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 397,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1380112272, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-09-25T12:31:12Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-09-25T12:31:42Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2013-09-25T12:31:41Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 10,
                        "syncingTo" : "host2:27102"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "host2:27102",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 397,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1380112272, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-09-25T12:31:12Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-09-25T12:31:42Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2013-09-25T12:31:41Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 2,
                        "syncingTo" : "host0:27100"
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.  There is an open ticket about rs.status() showing the primary as syncingTo when run from a secondary if the current primary was a secondary in the past ( [SERVER-9989](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9989) ).  Fix verion is 2.5.1